# Android spinner dialogMode style

Tags: android, xml, spinner

I have my spinner, but I wanted to use dialog mode (it's easier to choose item). Is there any way to change dialog style? It's white and boring.

Btw. I'd like to change its style using XML

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
Spinner
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinnerHour"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined" />
```

use the spinnermode parameter for the dialog and use the style parameter to choose a different style.
You can also create your own styles for them.